# Full Calendar GetEvents() method call not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, fullcalendar

I am trying to fetch events from my database, but I can't get it to work. The events aren't being displayed in my calendar and in my web console, I get:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Exception thrown:

**The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'start' of non-nullable type 'System.Double' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult GetEvents(Double, Double)' in 'ForecastCalendar.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters**

Here is the methods in my controller that I use to fetch events:

```
public JsonResult GetEvents(double start, double end)
{
    var events = new List<Event>();

    var dtstart = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start);
    var dtend = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(end);

    DateTime currStart;
    DateTime currEnd;

    foreach (Event ev in db.Events)
    {
        currStart = Convert.ToDateTime(ev.StartDate);
        currEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(ev.EndDate);

        events.Add(new Event()
        {
            ID = ev.ID,
            Title = ev.Title,
            StartDate = currStart,
            EndDate = currEnd,
            AllDay = true,
            EventType = ev.EventType,
            Hours = ev.Hours
        });
    }

    var rows = events.ToArray();
    return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
{
    var origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp);
}
```

Below is my event model:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ForecastCalendar.Models
{
    public enum EventType
    {
        BAU,
        Project,
        AnnualLeave
    }

    public class Event
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid date.")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid date.")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "End Date")]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Title cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z- ]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid characters used. A-Z or a-z, '-' and ' ' allowed.")]
        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EnumDataType(typeof(EventType), ErrorMessage = "Submitted value is not valid.")]
        [Display(Name = "Type")]
        public EventType? EventType { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public double Hours { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Boolean AllDay { get; set; }

        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the JavaScript where the calendar is rendered.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@Styles.Render("~/Content/fullcalendar")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fullcalendar")

<br />
<div class="container">
    <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
<br />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'prev,next today' },
        defaultView: 'month',
        weekends: false,
        editable: false,
        events: "/Home/GetEvents/"
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I have changed my GetEvents() method to conform to the event type in full calendar.

```
public JsonResult GetEvents(double start, double end)
        {
            var fromDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start);
            var toDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(end);

            var rslt = db.Events;

            List<Event> result = new List<Event>();

            foreach (var item in rslt)
            {
                Event ev = new Event();
                ev.ID = item.ID;
                ev.Title = item.Title;
                ev.Hours = item.Hours;
                ev.StartDate = item.StartDate;
                ev.EndDate = item.EndDate;
                ev.EventType = item.EventType;
                ev.AllDay = ev.AllDay;
            }

            var resultList = result;

            var eventList = from e in resultList
                            select new
                            {
                                id = e.ID,
                                title = e.Title,
                                start = e.StartDate,
                                end = e.EndDate,
                                allDay = e.AllDay
                            };

            var rows = eventList.ToArray();
            return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: So whats the exception being thrown? A Http 500 response means that something went wrong on the server.

Comment: Please provide full error information(it is attached with error callback), since error 500 usually means that something crushed on the server side.

Comment: I have added the exception into my OP.

Comment: Please read the error :). The start parmeter is null and it must not be null. You should either define it as nullable, or ensure that form javascript u do not send it as null/undefined.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, I was hoping someone might be able to explain why. It's how you are supposed to define the method for calling the events I believe but I'm still confused on how the whole thing works.

Answer (score 1):

Check the parameters you are receiving server side at GetMethods, that has a signature waiting two Double parameters, are not null.

In addition, you are sending a JSON object directly from your Model Event object. Then, client-side, this JSON object is directly injected as a source in fullcalendar. But fullcalendar is expecting for properties named as in the documentation, so `start` and `title` are mandatory properties.

From [fullcalendar doc Event object](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)

```
'start'
```

> The date/time an event begins. Required.
>
> A Moment-ish input, like an ISO8601 string. Throughout the API this
>   will become a real Moment object.

But your JSON object has no `start` property, but `StartDate`.

Now you can:

- Change your model to match the fullcalendar properties.
- Map server side the properties, so you return the JSON with the proper names.
- ...You could also map them client-side, but based on your current code would be tedious and dirty

Anyway, be sure that at client side you have your objects with `start` property.

Comment: I see your point, but I don't think this will make any difference. However, you've got me thinking. I think I need to map my events to match the event standard required?

Comment: Yes, that's another possibility. Whatever you do, server or client-side, the fullcalendar event object must have, at least, title and start properties. Now, when you do `return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` it's creating the properties with the names you have at the model, so StartDate instead of Start.

Comment: I renamed them above as you said and it still didn't work, so I think what I said about mapping them is correct, but I have no idea how to do so.

Comment: @JamesLloyd, could you give us the JSON object is being received at client-side? Then I can point you exactly where the error is. Anyway, I've updated my answer with further explanation.

Comment: I've updated my code to conform to this, but it still doesn't work, I will add it to my OP.

Comment: ... Wait a moment... You are doing a using a `start` variable at `GetEvents` that goes undefined from the request? Could you debug that `start` is not undefined at `var dtstart = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start);` I've updated my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105371/discussion-between-mario-levrero-and-james-lloyd).

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I have just run into the same problem after following some tutorials on how to implement the GetEvents method. On my end the calendar never hit the GetEvents method when I had it set up to expect two parameters of type double like this

```
public JsonResult GetEvents(double start, double end)
```

When looking at the error I saw that the calendar tried calling the following method:

```
/GetEvents?start=2013-12-01&end=2014-01-12&_=1386054751381
```

My calendar's defaultview is 'month'. Changing my GetEvents method to expect two strings

```
public JsonResult GetEvents(string start, string end)
```

and voila, when I refresh the page the Calendar tries to refresh and calls my GetEvents method. However, because you are now dealing with strings and not doubles you also need to change this part of your code:

```
var dtstart = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start);
var dtend = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(end);
```

to deal with the strings (formatted like this: "2013-12-01")